# Flow chart + presentation + handwriting tool for iPad

Tags: ipad-app, productivity, presentation

I want a tool that allows to draw a flowchart where each node of the chart would be a slide in a presentation.

It's specifications would be:

- To have a palette with all the nodes available, then be able to pick
  and connect some nodes.
- For each node I would like to have a slide attached, that would be
  shown when the node is activated in the presentation.
- Also I would like to add handwritten text, vector graphics, and
  pictures to the slides while in the editing phase.

[image]